# How to add mosby MVP structure to a dialog?

Tags: mosby

Im trying to write some dialogs that involves complex server calls.

Therefore I find it easier if i could just add some MVP stuff in the Dialog file directly.

However, there doesn't seem to be an MvpDialog.

What are some alternatives that I could do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FragmentDialogs will be part of next Mosby release, see here:
https://github.com/sockeqwe/mosby/pull/300/files

Snapshot should be available to try it out.